Vue: different ways to get reactive value
I'm a bit confused about so many different ways of getting reactive value.
What's the difference between prop.value, unref(prop) and toValue(prop)?
When should I use which method?

What is prop? It looks like a ref but this is not something to speculate about. toValue > unref > .value in terms of flexibility. This is primarily intended your own composables so you're not limited in a shape in which you provide an arg. Also unref(obj).value or toValue  makes more sense than obj.value.value, this is not something unheard of

Check the API docs page for any VueJS specific method and understand the differences:

unref


Returns the inner value if the argument is a ref, otherwise return
the argument itself. This is a sugar function for val = isRef(val) ?
val.value : val

In other words, it is some simple function that returns a value if you variable is either a ref or an actual simple vanilla JS value


toValue


Normalizes values / refs / getters to values. This is similar to unref(), except that it also normalizes getters. If the argument is a getter, it will be invoked and its return value will be returned.

This is adding getters to the mix, so that you need to make even less of a check.


.value is the usual access thing where you need to use it on a ref only, no point in using it on a string, object or anything in vanilla JS.

So .value is the most restrictive and harder one to use, because you need to care about what you use it on. The other ones are mostly useful wrapper methods that you could use on a lot of things to ignore their specific ways of accessing a value.
Check the linked pages for each of the methods for details.

I read documentation, just not clear about few things. Is there any reason to use .value instead of toValue()?

@Kindzoku toValue was only added in 3.3 so if your app is below that version then you don't really have a choice. But in the end, it's not a big deal either to write your own. So you could indeed have some toValue all the time and not use .value at all. There is no horrible drawback using toValue if it's the question haha. Also, some people might like to be consistent and always type a few characters to be explicit to some junior webdevs I guess. Read the official blog post here
